# ¿Cómo hacer tests en pyqt usando Qtest?

Tags: pyqt4

Hacer test es una buena práctica a la hora de programar, yo siempre he versionado mis software pero nunca he testiado, estoy aprendiendo a testiar mi *software* usando `unittest` y he visto que para `pyqt4` exite una librería en `pyqt` que se llama `QTest`. Estuve leyendo en un blog más o menos como usarlo pero no me funciona

```
class TestAboutWindow(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # inicializacion
        self.app, self.configuration = run_tests.init_application()()
        # creacion de main window
        self.mainWin = MainWindow()
        # SLOTS
        self.mainWin = pyqtmake.connections(self.mainWin)
        # ejecucion
        self.mainWin.show()
        QTest.qWaitForWindowShown(self.mainWin)

    def test_on_about_action(self):
        QTest.keyClick(self.mainWin, 'F1')
        QTest.qWaitForWindowShown(self.mainWin.about)
        self.assertIsInstance(self.mainWin.about, AboutWindow)

    def tearDown(self):
        # exit
        if hasattr(self.mainWin, 'about'):
            self.mainWin.about.close()
        self.mainWin.close()
        self.app.exit()
```

aquí esta el código de run_tests

```
import unittest

import sys


def run_functional_tests(pattern=None):
    print('Running tests...')
    if pattern is None:
        tests = unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover('tests')
    else:
        pattern_with_globs = ''.format(pattern)
        tests = unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover('tests', pattern_with_globs)
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(tests)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        run_functional_tests()
    else:
        run_functional_tests(pattern=sys.argv[1])
```

la variable `pyqtmake` no la encuentro en ningún lado. Alguien podría ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo estás siguiendo [este tutorial](http://danteslab.blogspot.com.ar/2014/02/probando-tu-codigo-con-unittest.html) , entiendo que `pyqtmake` no es un variable, en realidad es un módulo que te falta importar.